# How to disable email notifications for filtered messages in Postbox?

Tags: email, thunderbird, notifications, postbox

[Postbox](http://www.postbox-inc.com/) (which is based on the Thunderbird code) notifies me every time a new email arrives. I have some message filters in place which move some messages automatically from the Inbox to a different folder. I don't want to be notified if such filtered messages arrive. I only want to be notified, for messages in my Inbox.

For Thundebird there is the [FiltaQuilla](http://mesquilla.com/extensions/filtaquilla/) extension which supports a "Do Not Notify" filter action, but I think it isn't supported in Postbox. Is there something similar for Postbox?

Answer (score 2):

My workaround is a filter rule which does the following:

- "*Move message to*" a folder
- "*Mark As Read*"
- "*Add topic*" which I named "Incoming" so I can distinguish the new messages. After I read them I'm removing the topic.

"*Mark As Read*" prevents the notification.